# Increasing current by introducing another voltage source in series?

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, series

I have a voltage source connected to a load, and after sometime, introduced another voltage source, would the overall current increase?

Intially circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxYHNX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current in this circuit is 2A.

After sometime(t) I've introduced V2 to the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZZXNS.png)</sup>

Will the current to the load now increase to 5A?
Since the net voltage is 50V/10ohms= 5A?

Comment: Trust in ohms law.

Comment: Did you miss the fine print at the bottom left corner of your drawings?

Comment: In reality it depends on the quality of the voltage sources : are they BOTH capable of supplying 5 Amps?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the solution to this question is from Ohm's Law.

As you said, the current will eventually increase to 5A since the source of energy as increased and the resistance of the circuit is the same.